# Taming the Select - Don't replace disabled OPTION

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found a great piece of Javascript called Taming Select. I know it's quite old but has worked absolute wonders with rendering the < select > input into a UL dropdown list.

My problem is that my < select > DOM element has dynamically disabled < option > children, yet this piece of code does not discern whether it is disabled or not.

I was wondering a couple of things:

1. How do I get Javascript to identify disabled < options >?
2. Should I delete the DOM element completely or inject CSS classes into the newly made list items to disable them with user-select and pointer-events?

I have been on the search for nearly 8 hours and I can't seem to figure out how to do number 1 on my list.

I have tried getElementsByTagName('option').disabled and other variations of getElementsByTagName and nothing happens; even when I modify some examples in W3Schools.

Below is the code for TamingSelect:

```
    function tamingselect()
{
    if(!document.getElementById && !document.createTextNode){return;}

// Classes for the link and the visible dropdown
    var ts_selectclass='turnintodropdown';  // class to identify selects
    var ts_listclass='turnintoselect';      // class to identify ULs
    var ts_boxclass='dropcontainer';        // parent element
    var ts_triggeron='activetrigger';       // class for the active trigger link
    var ts_triggeroff='trigger';            // class for the inactive trigger link
    var ts_dropdownclosed='dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
    var ts_dropdownopen='dropdownvisible';  // open dropdown
/*
    Turn all selects into DOM dropdowns
*/
    var count=0;
    var toreplace=new Array();
    var sels=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(var i=0;i<sels.length;i++){
        if (ts_check(sels[i],ts_selectclass))
        {
            var hiddenfield=document.createElement('input');
            hiddenfield.name=sels[i].name;
            hiddenfield.type='hidden';
            hiddenfield.id=sels[i].id;
            hiddenfield.value=sels[i].options[0].value;
            sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(hiddenfield,sels[i])
            var trigger=document.createElement('a');
            ts_addclass(trigger,ts_triggeroff);
            trigger.href='#';
            trigger.onclick=function(){
                ts_swapclass(this,ts_triggeroff,ts_triggeron)
                ts_swapclass(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],ts_dropdownclosed,ts_dropdownopen);
                return false;
            }
            trigger.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sels[i].options[0].text));
            sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(trigger,sels[i]);
            var replaceUL=document.createElement('ul');
            for(var j=0;j<sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option').length;j++)
            {
                var newli=document.createElement('li');
                var newa=document.createElement('a');
                newli.v=sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].value;
                newli.elm=hiddenfield;
                newli.istrigger=trigger;
                newa.href='#';
                newa.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option')[j].text));
                newli.onclick=function(){ 
                    this.elm.value=this.v;
                    ts_swapclass(this.istrigger,ts_triggeron,ts_triggeroff);
                    ts_swapclass(this.parentNode,ts_dropdownopen,ts_dropdownclosed)
                    this.istrigger.firstChild.nodeValue=this.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                    return false;
                }
                newli.appendChild(newa);
                replaceUL.appendChild(newli);
            }
            ts_addclass(replaceUL,ts_dropdownclosed);
            var div=document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(replaceUL);
            ts_addclass(div,ts_boxclass);
            sels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div,sels[i])
            toreplace[count]=sels[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

/*
    Turn all ULs with the class defined above into dropdown navigations
*/  

    var uls=document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    for(var i=0;i<uls.length;i++)
    {
        if(ts_check(uls[i],ts_listclass))
        {
            var newform=document.createElement('form');
            var newselect=document.createElement('select');
            for(j=0;j<uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a').length;j++)
            {
                var newopt=document.createElement('option');
                newopt.value=uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].href;  
                newopt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[j].innerHTML)); 
                newselect.appendChild(newopt);
            }
            newselect.onchange=function()
            {
                window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            }
            newform.appendChild(newselect);
            uls[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newform,uls[i]);
            toreplace[count]=uls[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        toreplace[i].parentNode.removeChild(toreplace[i]);
    }
    function ts_check(o,c)
    {
        return new RegExp('\\b'+c+'\\b').test(o.className);
    }
    function ts_swapclass(o,c1,c2)
    {
        var cn=o.className
        o.className=!ts_check(o,c1)?cn.replace(c2,c1):cn.replace(c1,c2);
    }
    function ts_addclass(o,c)
    {
        if(!ts_check(o,c)){o.className+=o.className==''?c:' '+c;}
    }
}

window.onload=function()
{
    tamingselect();
    // add more functions if necessary
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have very very little Javascript experience (to be honest, the closest I have come to studying it was ActionScript 10 years ago).

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

1. You're looking for the .hasAttribute() function which returns a bool.
   ie. el.hasAttribute('disabled').

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute

As mentioned in the comment, to actually iterate through the options to check for the attribute you should do the following:

```
// returns an array like HTMLCollection of the elements that match the 
// tag
let options = document.getElementsByTagName('option')

// uses the array method forEach on the HTMLCollection.
// note that HTMLCollections do not natively have the forEach method 
// but still act behave normal arrays when using iteration.

Array.prototype.forEach.call( options, el => { 
    el.hasAttribute('disabled')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have been playing around with the code and cannot seem to figure out where to put it. Chrome DevTools keeps telling me that .hasAttribute is not a function.

Comment: let options = document.getElementsByTagName('option')
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( options, el => el.hasAttribute('disabled'))

This will iterate through your el array of options and check each for the disabled attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me. But I cannot figure out how or where to run this code in the tamingselect.js file I have so I can stop all disabled <option>s from outputting to an <li>. I just have no idea when it comes to Javascript. Might need to look at another path.